# Scrapy. Python. Comparing data extracted from Xpath with string?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am **web-scraping** some **year** values from a webpage using **scrapy** and trying to check to see if the value is 2015 but I can't seem to compare the value with the string '2015' properly.

this is my Python code
 `

```
for i in response.xpath('//********/*******/*******"]'):
    if i.xpath('./******/******/text()').extract() == '2015' :
        item['testing'] = 'yes'
    else :
        item['testing'] = 'no'
    yield item`
```

even when the extracted value is 2015 it still prints no.

Help would be much appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Have you printed the output to see what you get? I think _extract_ returns a list of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use `.xpath` or `.css` inside a selector, what you get is a `SelectorList`, which as you could imagine, is a `list` not a `string`. Maybe you are only getting one element inside this list, so to compare that you could use:

```
i.xpath('./******/******/text()').extract()[0]
```

or

```
''.join(i.xpath('./******/******/text()').extract())
```

or better

```
i.xpath('./******/******/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting back a list from the `extract()` call instead of a string.  If you just want a string, try calling `extract_first()` instead and comparing that against your `'2015'` string.

*Source:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html*

> To actually extract the textual data, you must call the selector
>   .extract() method, as follows:
>
> ```
> >>> response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
> [u'Example website']
> ```
>
> If you want to extract only first matched element, you can call the
>   selector .extract_first()
>
> ```
> >>> response.xpath('//div[@id="images"]/a/text()').extract_first()
> u'Name: My image 1 '
> ```